# How to put radio button on the editText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

This is a gender check button.

[image: I want to deploy like this]

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtSex"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:text=""/>
```

Comment: What purpose you need, like this.?

Comment: Please click  the link to view the picture.

Comment: you need just a line or `edittext` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Gender" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Male" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Female" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Its view. OP is asking about `EditText`

Comment: @TejasPandya i know thats why i added in my answer try this way

Comment: @NAMGYUKANG Glad to have been of help

Comment: `Editext` confuse the whole thing +1

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just want a line underneath your RadioGroup. Just use a View with a height of 1dp and a background color.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this type of UI takes Two Radio button horizontally. after take View set height according to bottom line height. and put it to vertically of both radio buttons.

Comment: did you try this type of solution before ?

Answer (score 0):

if you need only underline below the RadioButton then there is no need to put it in edittext. just put the view as shown below,

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ccc" />
```